# Have jquery ajax (php) scripts run one after another instead of at the same time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here's the code - this runs as soon as the document is loaded (inside $(document).ready(function(){ ) Is there a way to code this so that the next ajax query will run after the current one is finished?  I want to create more ajax calls on the page, but they will not execute until all the queued calls are completed.  If each call would run after the other is executed, this will give new ajax calls a chance to get to the front of the next script insead of at the end of all 30.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
for (var x=0;x<=30;x++)
{
emailnumber = '<?php echo $storage->countMessages(); ?>'-x;
dataString='emailnumber='+emailnumber+'&url=<?php echo $url; ?>&email=<?php echo $email_address; ?>';

    $.ajax({

       type: "POST",

    url: "phpdocument.php",

    data: dataString,

    success: function(msg){

            $('#results').append(msg);

        }

    });


}
```

**Edit:  Should I be using the setTimeout function somewhere?**

Comment: maybe I can keep async to true and put in some javascript that causes a 4 second delay each time it passes througH?  Each script takes 2-4 seconds to execute.

Comment: I decided to create a function that runs - and when the ajax query is successfully finished, it will call the next function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `async` to `false` in the options for your `ajax()` call. But, know this: synchronous Ajax requests may lock the browser. This is because the Ajax request will halt further execution until complete. In other words, you won't get out of the `for` loop until all the Ajax requests have completed.

```
for (var x = 0; x <= 30; x++) {
    emailnumber = '<?php echo $storage->countMessages(); ?>' - x;
    dataString = 'emailnumber=' + emailnumber + '&url=<?php echo $url; ?>&email=<?php echo $email_address; ?>';

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "phpdocument.php",

        data: dataString,

        success: function(msg) {

            $('#results').append(msg);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: How would I be able to make it so it wouldn't lock and a new query would go to the front of the queue?  Is there a way to slow down when each one goes without turning off async?  Maybe I  shouldn't use a loop? - maybe it should call one php document, which should call another ajax php call?

Comment: You could make the second ajax request from the success function in the first ajax request.  `success: function() {secondAjaxFunction();}`

Comment: The only way it won't lock is if you use `asynchronous` mode. JavaScript executes on a single thread with the exception of `asynchronous` requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
FindEmail('<?php echo $storage->countMessages(); ?>');


    $(".unsubscribe_button").live("click", function(event){

        var thetd = $(this).parents(".unsubscribe_td");

        thetd.empty().append('"loading image url here" alt="" />');
        var senderemail = thetd.prev().html();
        var emailid = $(this).attr('id');
        var dataString='email=<?php echo $_SESSION[email_address]; ?>&emailid='+emailid;
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "php script location",

            data: dataString,       

            success: function(msg){

                thetd.empty();
                thetd.append('success image url here');

        }

        });
        return false;

    });
```

Here's what I'm using that fulfilled my needs.  Anyone see any flaws with this?